# Given a pid, how to check if the process was run via sudo?

Tags: macos, sudo

Given a pid, I have a requirement to fetch the process username and also to detect if the process was run via sudo. I am using getpwuid to fetch the username but having trouble detecting if the process was run via sudo.I checked getuid, geteuid and both of them return root. I also came across $SUDO_USER variable but do not know how to make it work with a pid. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: So is it for OS X or Linux? Pick one...

Comment: I guess you could check the "process tree" to see if sudo is involved. ```ps -axf``` on GNU/Linux (if my fingers are remembering correctly).

Comment: @heemay ..osx fr nw!

Comment: @Edmundo consider this , i have an app a.exe ...if i run it doing sudo ./a may be cmd would tell me that there's sudo involved ...but if i do a sudo su and then do ./a , i don't think in that case , the suggested method would work

Comment: As far as I can remember, the -f option (from _forest_) of ps will show you a tree where you will see that .a is running inside bash inside su inside sudo in that case. http://serverfault.com/questions/359856/what-is-the-difference-between-sudo-i-and-sudo-su

Comment: @Edmundo...thanks, any suggestions on how to do it programmatically in c ++,